# How to Add API controller (Web API 2) in Asp.Net (aspx) application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a asp.net (aspx) c# web application on .net framework 4.5, I have to create a web api in this application that will consume in third party CMS(Infusionsoft) Http POST campaign.

Comment: good luck with that. Now what exactly is your question?

Comment: Explanation != question. Please read this: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dev-Systematix is asking a goal-oriented question, but this is a question-oriented site.

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms this may help

Comment: We could help, even if it's a goal oriented question, but the way the OP formulated the question shows that he has not done any kinda of search on the subject, and just want to be spoon fed a solution

Comment: I think a lack of `?` means that it isn't a question imo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add webapi controller in asp.net C# application

Step 1: Add new webapi controller using Add New Item process 
[image]

Step 2: Added PaymentController

```
 public class PaymentController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

Step 3: Add Routing information in Application_stat methd inside Global.asax.cs file

Add Using namespaces:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;



 protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
```

Step 4: Run application and it will raise below exception:

*Attempt by security transparent method 'DebtFREE.Global.Application_Start(System.Object, System.EventArgs)' to access security critical field 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional' failed.
Assembly 'DebtFREE, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.*

[image]

Step 5: Go to AssemblyInfo.cs (Bin/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs) and comment below line.
[image]
    [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]

Step 6: Cheers, run application and browse url: http://localhost:2071/api/payment
API is wokring togather aspx (asp.net) application.

[image]